# How to format date from word to number? Ex. Nov 4, 2004 to 11/04/2004 using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datepicker

I am new to Jquery can anyone help me or give me sample on this one.
How to format date from word to number? Ex. Nov 4, 2004 to 11/04/2004 using JQuery?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you using any datepicker ?

Comment: Yes @MansukhKhandhar..

Comment: the id of my datepicker is "bday"

Comment: var date = $('#bday').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val(); ?

Comment: jquery datepicker library name .. not field name

Comment: or share script in snippet OR fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var now = new Date('Nov 4, 2004');
var date = now.getDate();
var year = now.getFullYear();
var month = now.getMonth();
var date1 = date < 10 ? "0"+date : date;
console.log(month+1+"/"+date1+"/"+year)
```

1. Add 1 to month because it will start at 0

Comment: Thank you very much @guradio you are my idol from now on. God bless :)

Comment: @RamilSignh glad to help amte happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

html

```
    <input id="thedate" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="converteddate" type="text" /><br />
    <input id="thesubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    //Nov 4, 2004
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M d, y',
        altField: '#converteddate',
        altFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
    });

});
```